# Calling a function not working

Tags: python, function, class, blackjack

I have my blackjack game working great (first project, still a beginner). But to keep looping once the game is finished I now need to implement functions and classes I think.

Without copying over all of my code, this is the skeleton of my project so far. I split it into two functions because I think it just makes it a little neater... but if I shouldn't do that, let me know.

```
(couple of imports)
(couple of variables declared)

class Game:

    def newGame(self):
        (code)
        (Game.choices)
    def choices(self):
        (code)
        (Game.newGame)

Game.newGame()
```

Shouldn't this call the first function, which will in turn call the second function?

Comment: They need to be called by an instance of `Game`, unless you specify them as class methods or static methods

Comment: That may (eventually) do what you want, but that's not how you want to do it.

Comment: Fair enough, then how DO I want to do it Ignacio? any help appreciated, I haven't done a lot of coding before.

Answer (score 1):

`newGame` needs an object before it can be called (that's why *self* is a parameter) do this:

```
x = Game()
x.newGame()
```

or (as was pointed out in the comments):

```
Game().newGame()
```

Comment: or `Game().newGame()`